# Create pointer to member for map value type in vc2010

Tags: c++, visual-c++

We have a problem porting our code to the slightly less old version 2010 of VC++.

The issues is caused by the implementation of map in VC which results in a derived to base conversion of a `pointer-to-member` in a `non-type-argument` being required:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename MapValueType, int MapValueType::*var>
bool f (MapValueType const & v);

int main ()
{
  typedef std :: map<int, int> MapType;
  MapType m;
  std :: find_if (m.begin ()
      , m.end ()
      , f<MapType::value_type, & MapType::value_type::second> );
}
```

The following message is generated:

> Standard conversion from pointer-to-member of base to pointer-to-member of derived is not applied for template arguments file.cc(x) : error C2973:
>   'f' : invalid template argument 'int std::_Pair_base<_Ty1,_Ty2>::* '

So it seems that the implementation of `value_type` in `std::map` has the pair  in a base class.

Any ideas on how to solve this *and* keep the `pointer-to-member` as a `non-type-argument`?

Is our only option to change the structure so that `f` is a `functor` with a member `pointer-to-member`?

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but why do you need to pass that pointer to member?

Comment: what's with the spaces surrounding the `::` and other lexical tokens?

Comment: yeah, just to clarify the previous question, why simpler `template <typename MapItemType> bool f (MapItemType const & v);` doesn't work for you?

Comment: @AndyProwl: Sometimes we operate on `.second` and sometimes `.first`.

Comment: @RichardCorden: then why not using a `bool` as a template argument?

Comment: @AndyProwl: ...OK, and then choose between first and second based on the value of the 'bool'.  My preference would be to add the member - that way I wouldn't have to change the code doing the work.  But this would definitely work.

Comment: @RichardCorden: if you really can't change the code doing the work, then you could follow the VS2010-specific hack I added to my answer. but if I were you I would just cleanup the design, it will pay off in the future anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that your code should compile IMO (and it does on GCC 4.7.2 and Clang 3.2), I believe your design is unnecessarily intricate. A `pair` only has two member variables, so you are going to access either the first or the second.

I do not see the need for a functor object either: just use a boolean template argument to determine whether the code shall work on the `first` or on the `second` member variable.
Here's a possibility:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename MapValueType, bool first>
bool f (MapValueType const & p)
{
    auto& v = (first) ? p.first : p.second;
    // ... do your work on v ...    
}

int main ()
{
    typedef std :: map<int, int> MapType;
    MapType m;

    // Will work on the `first` member
    std::find_if(m.begin (), m.end (), f<MapType::value_type, true>);

    // Will work on the `second` member
    std::find_if(m.begin (), m.end (), f<MapType::value_type, false>);
}
```

If you really cannot change your client code nor your code inside the `f()` function, then you could go for this VS2010-specific hack:

```
// Add "_MyBase" here... works, but ugly IMO
template <typename MapValueType, int MapValueType::_Mybase::* var>
bool f(MapValueType const & v);

// And the client side could stay unchanged...
int main ()
{
    typedef std :: map<int, int> MapType;
    MapType m;
    std::find_if(
        m.begin(), 
        m.end (), 
        f<MapType::value_type, &MapType::value_type::second>
        );
}
```

Finally, if your code has to compile on other platforms *and* all the constraints on the non-modifiability of the function's and client code still hold, then you can define a preprocessor macro that expands to `_Mybase::` for VS2010 and to the empty string for other compilers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1).  Part of the motivation for asking the question was driven by surprise that the code no longer works.  If this was part of an API that can't change - how would you address this?

Comment: @RichardCorden: updated the answer with a workaround (honestly I wouldn't go for it, as it is strongly VS2010-specific, but... well, that's up to you in the end)

Comment: Would have to add the bool or the member before going this route - the code needs to compile with g++ too.

Comment: @RichardCorden: if 1) it has to compile with g++ too, 2) you cannot change the client code, and 3) you cannot change the code that does  the work, then your only solution is to adapt the hack above by defining a macro that expands into `_Mbyase::` for VS2010 and into the empty string for other compilers. but again, I'd go for the `bool`

Comment: For the use cases we have, using a 'bool' flag ends up to be the simplest solution.  The only difference to what you have here is that I am using a specialization to select the .first or .second at compile time.

Comment: @RichardCorden: i think a decent compiler would choose it at compile-time anyway, since that gets translated into an `if (false)` or `if (true)`. this way you don't have to replicate the code. but of course it's up to you, specialization is conceptually fine.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you insist on keeping the pointer-to-member as non-type-template parameter/argument?

Anyway, I think that you could use this, if you can be limited to either Visual Studio 2010 or compilers with `decltype()`

```
template <typename Class, typename Type>
Class
get_class_type (Type Class:: *);
//...
it = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(),
    f<decltype(get_class_type(&MapType::value_type::second)), &MapType::value_type::second>);
```

Comment: The short answer is because if I can I would prefer not to have to modify the code which I know is working, or in otherwords Lazyness!

Comment: Just to mention that I've marked Andy's as being the Answer - but this is only based on it suiting my dev environment.  One of the compilers we use is g++ 4.2.4 which doesn't have decltype.  But your solution will solve the problem from now on.